# Problema al intentar dibujar un triángulo isósceles

Tags: c#

Pues no logro realizarlo, ya llevo varios intentos y algo me falla

Me pueden ayudar ?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.Clear();
        // dibujo de cada linea (bucle externo)
        for (int fila = 1; fila <= 7; fila++)
        {
            //dibuja espacios en blanco (1er bucle interno)
            for (int espacios = 7 - fila; espacios > 0; espacios--)
                Console.Write(" ");// dibuja los espacios en blanco)
                Console.Write("*");// dibuja el triángulo)
                Console.WriteLine(" ");// dibuja los espacios en blanco)
        }
    }
```

Comment: ¿Cuál es el resultado que esperas obtener?

Comment: Perdona @PaperBirdMaster, no había visto tu pregunta. Gracias por molestarte. Al final pude solucionarlo. Me faltaba el segundo bucle for. Muchas gracias

Comment: Ningún problema. Pero para la próxima pregunta de ese tipo, procura añadir a la pregunta una muestra de la salida esperada, para ti puede estar claro pero para otros usuarios no lo está.

Answer (score 5):

Ahhh, que tonta, ya está, conseguido, me faltaba un bucle for

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.Clear();
    // dibujo de cada linea (bucle externo)
    for (int fila=1; fila <= 7; fila ++)
    {
    //dibuja espacios en blanco (1er bucle interno)
    for (int espacios = 7 - fila; espacios > 0; espacios--)
        Console.Write(" ");// espai en blanc
        // dibuja estrellas (2º bucle interno)
    for (int conta = 1; conta < (2 * fila); conta++)
        Console.Write("*");
        Console.WriteLine(" ");
    }
}
```